# `transition` is undefined using rollup to bundle d3 modules

Tags: d3.js, rollupjs

My code looks like this:

```
// foo.js
import {select} from 'd3-selection';
import {transition} from 'd3-transition';

console.log(select('body').transition);
```

The console returns `undefined`.

This seems related to issue https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/13, then I added the empty import declaration:

```
import {select} from 'd3-selection';
import {transition} from 'd3-transition';
import 'd3-transition';

console.log(select('body').transition);
```

but still the console returns `undefined`.

What is the right way to set `selection.prototype.transition`?

Answer (score 2):

The issue was related to a conflict between d3-selection and d3-transition versions.

Before:

```
"d3-selection": "^1.0.5",
"d3-transition": "^1.1.0",
```

After:

```
"d3-selection": "^1.1.0",
"d3-transition": "^1.1.0",
```

Now the following code works as expected:

```
// foo.js
import {select} from 'd3-selection';
import {transition} from 'd3-transition';

console.log(select('body').transition);
```